# How do I delete the string "-" that comes twice in a row in a list?

Tags: python

for example:

```
print(list) 
output = ['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '-', '1', '-', '2']
```

the result(output) should be:

```
['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3',  '-', '1', '-', '2']
```

I tried for like 1 hour but couldn't find a solution.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Join the list, replace -- by -, split the split it again. I'm on cellphone typing code is painful

Comment: Is it precisely two '-' or is it two or *more*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) + list comprehension

**Ex**

```
from itertools import groupby

test_list = ['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '-', '1', '-', '2']
output = [i[0] for i in groupby(test_list)]
print(output)
```

**O/P:**

```
['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '1', '-', '2']
```

Remove only consecutive `'-'`

**Ex.**

```
from itertools import groupby

test_list = ['5','5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '-', '1', '-', '2']
# create consecutive element group of list
grouped_L =  [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(test_list)]
output = []
for i in grouped_L:
    if i[0] == '-' and i[1] >=2 :
        output.extend(i[0])
    else:
        output.extend(list(i[0]*i[1]))

print(output)
```

O/P:

```
['5', '5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '1', '-', '2']
```

Comment: This removes any consecutive characters, not just consecutive dashes.

Comment: The updated answer is incredibly inefficient by incurring a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is, loop through the elements and keep adding to another list unless you find an element which is '-' and the index next to it is also '-'.

```py
>>> l = ['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '-', '1', '-', '2']
>>> final = []
>>> for i in range(len(l)-1): # Iterate to the last second element
...   if l[i] == '-' and l[i]==l[i+1]: 
...     continue 
...   final.append(l[i]) 
... 
>>> final
['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '1', '-']
```

Comment: What if you wanted to replace consecutive '-' elements with one when just two appear together? This will replace N consecutive '-' elements where N >= 2. The OP's question was not precise in that detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filterDoubleDash(arg):
    output = []
    current = ''
    previous = ''
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        current = arg[i]
        if not (current == '-' and previous == '-'):
            output.append(current)
        previous = current
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pair adjacent items of the list by zipping the list with itself, but pad one of them with an invalid value, so that you can filter out adjacent items that are both equal to `'-'`:

```
[b for a, b in zip([''] + lst, lst) if not a == b == '-']
```

Given your sample input as variable `lst`, this returns:

```
['5', '-', '8', '2', '-', '3', '-', '1', '-', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear from the OP's question nor his example whether he only wanted to remove the extra `'-'` element when precisely two of these occur adjacent in the list. If that is the case, then this will do it in place.

If you want to handle adjacent `'-'` when they occur two or more times, then replace the test

```
if n == 1:
```

with

```
if n >= 1:
```

The code:

```
l = ['-', '-', '8', '-', '-', '-', '2', '-', '3', '-', '-', '1', '-', '2']

i = len(l) - 1
while i >= 1:
    if l[i] != '-':
        i -= 1
        continue
    last_i = i
    # found a '-'
    while i > 0 and l[i-1] == '-':
        i -= 1
    first_i = i
    n = last_i - first_i
    if n == 1: # or if n >= 1: to handle 2 or more adjacent '-' elements
        del l[first_i:last_i]
    i -= 1

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['-', '8', '-', '-', '-', '2', '-', '3', '-', '1', '-', '2']
```